# Indeterminate Roma tomato growing in clusters

Tags: identification, tomatoes

Last year I grew an indeterminate Roma tomato that grew in clusters.  The fruits were on the small side and I think there was kind of a point at the bottom of each one.  I can't remember what kind it was.  It was not an early producer but it was extremely prolific.  Any idea what it might have been?

Comment: Where did you get the plant or seeds?

Comment: Don't forget that Roma itself is a breed of tomato (it's not just a fruit shape), and it can be nippled sometimes, in my experience (BonniePlants' version in 2014, in my area), and it is extremely prolific. But it's shorter than San Marzano, and it isn't indeterminate (although it does fruit all season). When talking about the fruit shape, it's probably best to just call them paste tomatoes instead of Roma, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know where you got the plants and what state/zone you live in.

Yours sounds like it could be one of three Roma varieties all smaller than they appear:

**10 Fingers of Naples**
[image: 10 Fingers of Naples]

**Martino’s Roma**
[image: Martino’s Roma]

**San Marzano**
[image: San Marzano]

Comment: The San Marzano photo looks right, thanks.  I live in upstate NY (southern tier, which means not far from PA).

Comment: @aparente001 No problem, would you mind marking the answer as accepted if it helped you?

Comment: I want to go back where I bought last year's plant and see if I can buy the same thing.  Also I want to check the label of what I planted this year and ask you about it.

Comment: @aparente001 Have you done this? I'm still happy to answer questions in comments even if you accept the answer. The goal is to help people in the end.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a San Marzano where I live.  Then I need to see if it grows and produces like the thing I had last year.  I'll check in again in a couple months.